# Can't find price between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I use:

```
rails 4.1.1
ruby 2.1.1
thinking sphinx 3.1.1
mysql2
```

object_index.rb:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :object, :with => :active_record do
  indexes price, :sortable => true
  ...
  has created_at, updated_at
end
```

In sphinx config:

```
 sql_attr_float = price
 also try
 sql_attr_uint = price
 result was the same
```

When I try to search object wich price is between X and Y:

```
Object.search :with=> {:price => 100..900}
```

I got all records without between, but it work's.

When I try:

```
Object.search :conditions => {:with=> {:price => 100..800}}
or
Object.search :conditions => {:with=> {:price => 100.0..800.0}} for float
```

I got an error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index object_core: unsupported filter type 'intrange' on string column - SELECT * FROM `object_core` WHERE `price` BETWEEN 100 AND 800 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META
or for float
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index object_core: unsupported filter type 'floatrange' on string column - SELECT * FROM `object_core` WHERE `price` BETWEEN 100.0 AND 900.0 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META
```

How can I fix it and use search in range for price?

upd:
schema.db
when I make it integer problem was the same:

```
  t.float  "price",  null: false
```

`thinging_sphinx` generate this config file, put it here - http://pastebin.com/USGABqdt

Comment: What's the type of your column "price" ? Can you show us the `schema.rb` for this table ?

Comment: schema: t.float  "price",  null: false

Comment: Can you add to your question the `sphinx.conf` file ?

Comment: sure - http://pastebin.com/USGABqdt

Comment: also i try to change it with sql_attr_uint and sql_attr_bool - http://pastebin.com/4U8qRaZr - but result was the same

Comment: The problem comes from this line `sql_field_string = price`. As I thought you're trying to find a number into a string. You can create a `sphinx_scope` into your model. It's easier to manage and seems to work. [Official Github issues](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/740)

Comment: Thank you, something like: sphinx_scope(:price){{:price=>:float}}? And why do not work indexes price :type => :float? I do not understand?

Comment: Rather like `sphinx_scope(:interesting_price){:with=> {:price => 100.0..800.0}}`

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it, but i need to find Object wich price is between min and max that i get from user

Comment: This method could work for a static usage. In your case it won't in my mind.

Comment: It is not a good news for me..  Anywhere, are there any other ways to make this type of search?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I know only these 2 ways to make this type of search. You can try to open an issue on the Github. Pat is really quick to answer.

Comment: 2 ways.. Can you tell in short how could it work? Thank you!

Comment: The one you've tried and what I've told you about the scope.

Comment: i fix it. i used price as field instead of attributes

Answer (score 2):

I fix my problem! 
I wrote in /inidices/realty_index.rb

```
indices :price
```

But I should write

```
has :price, :type => float
```

Because price is not a field for search, but attribut for sorting.

```
Fields are the content for your search queries

Attributes are used for sorting, filtering and grouping your search results
```

And it works!